# Regex to match LESS variable declarations

Tags: javascript, regex, less

I'm making an analysis tool for a LESS project that I'm working on and I'm having problems formulating the right regular expression in javascript to match LESS variables in a remote file, which only contains less variable declarations and comments.

Here is a sample of what the format of the remote file contents look like:

```
// Little bit of commenting here
@foo: bar;
@bar: "http://google.com";

// Little bit more here...
@example-string: "some string";
@example-number: 10;
```

Once this file is loaded via AJAX, my javascript passes the contents to my getVars() function, which is supposed to match everything from the at symbol (@) to the semicolon:

```
function getVars(input) {
    return input.match(/@.*;/gm);
}
```

This returns an array of strings containing variable declarations, which I can then map to a javascript object. Everything seems to stay in-tact except the @bar variable value stops right before the colon in the string, like this:

```
@bar: "http
```

To my knowledge, the colon character is not a reserved character in javascript regular expressions. Can anyone help fix my regular expression?

---

**EDIT: (with updated solution)**

So I made a mistake and felt like another part of my program wasn't important to my problem, but of course... that's where the problem was. After my regex would return an array of matches (which worked fine even though it was lazy), it would split each item at the colon character and assign the zero and first indexes as a key and value in my javascript object. I wasn't paying attention to the fact that the absolute url also has a colon in it.

So here's my new regex and the rest of the solution: (granted, its just part of a larger application)

```
// Return array of variable declarations where 'input' is the raw file contents (which contains end of line characters: \n)
function getDeclarations(input) {
    // matches @,
    // then one or more of any word, hyphen or underscore,
    // then zero or more whitespace,
    // then zero or more of any character
    // then a semicolon,
    // then end the match at zero or more forward slashes followed by any character (comments)
    return input.match(/@[\w-_]+:\s*.*;[\/.]*/gm);
}

// Map a single declaration to a key/value pair and return the object
function mapDeclaration(declaration) {
    var parts = declaration.split(':'),
        key = sanitizeVarKey(parts.shift()), // get just the first item
        value = sanitizeVarValue(parts.join(':')); // join all the remaining items

    return { key: value };
}

// Return variable key with at symbol removed
function sanitizeVarKey(input) {
    return input.replace(/@/, '');
}

// Return variable value with leading white space and the semicolon removed
function sanitizeVarValue(input) {
    return input.replace(/^\s+|;$/gm, '');
}
```

Comment: let me ask you this, what if the LESS variable declaration was somehting like this? `@foo: "http;//www.google.com";` your regex would fail.

Comment: Can't replicate your problem. Here's the stub: https://regex101.com/r/uF3nJ4/1

Comment: @iismathwizard actually it won't fail in your example. `.*` is greedy

Comment: @ZoffDino ahh, good catch. When i was testing it I changed it to lazy out of habit

Comment: @iismathwizard It's not the main problem (since we could assume we don't usually have such `;` in urls, string or comments). The real problem is that the following code is also valid variable definition: `@var: {color: red;};` Though as @ZoffDino mentiond it won't while unti next `@` but now the next problem rises `newline` can appear anywhere between single Less tokens. Same way this code: `@var: {@color: red;};` is also valid and it will fail too.

Comment: @seven-phases-max that's fine, i was giving an example (good or not). It doesn't matter though, since i was wrong anyway. Also, OP I tried replicating this problem in javascript and I get the correct output.

Comment: @seven-phases-max also, as ZoffDino pointed out, `.*` is greedy and would capture that variable definition just fine

Comment: i figured my regex was far too simple, but i was frustrated that i couldnt understand why it would ever stop at the colon.

Comment: In other words I'm afraid the regex should also take newlines and nested `{}` blocks into account too.

Comment: @seven-phases-max the file comes back with \n characters which is why i have the "m" modifiers

Comment: @seven-phases-max actually, i was originally using /^@.*;$/gm as my regex because i was expecting all declarations to exist on separate lines.

Comment: @wavematt Aside of above concerns, I can't see why it's not working for you - [Demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/NqzMMj?editors=101). I suspect the problem is not the regex but elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @seven-phases-max i hate to admit this, but my problem was happening elsewhere in my code, like you just said haha. after i got the array of matches i was splitting each item at the colon but i didnt pay attention to the fact that the full url value also had a colon... thats my bad. ill edit my question and show my solution. thank you for pointing me in the right direction!